# setState doesn't update the state array

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

A user clicks the button, `onClick` I make an ajax post request and I'm trying to setState in my `.then()` and `.catch()` phases of my request. I keep getting

> "Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means
>   you have called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the ContactForm component."

What am I doing wrong?

```
const ContactForm = React.createClass({
componentDidMount() {
    this._mounted = true;
},
componentWillMount() {
    this._mounted = false;
},
getInitialState() {
    return {
        formSubmitted: false,
        formSuccess: false,
    }
},
submitForm(info) {
    this.props.setLoading(true);
    axios.post('/contact', info)
        .then(response => {
            this.handleSuccess(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.handlError(error);
        });
},
handleSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.props.setLoading(false);
    this.state.formSubmitted = true;
    this.state.formSuccess = true;
    if (this._mounted) {
        this.setState(this.state);
    }
},
handlError(error) {
    console.log("error")

    this.props.setLoading(false);
    this.state.formSubmitted = true;
    this.state.formSuccess = true;
    if (this._mounted) {
        this.setState(this.state);
    }
    console.log(error);
},
render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
            <div className="form-group">
                {this.state.formSubmitted == false ? <Form submitForm={this.submitForm} /> : null}
                {this.state.formSubmitted && this.state.formSuccess ? <FormSuccess /> : null}
                {this.state.formSubmitted && !this.state.formSuccess ? <FormError /> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not mutate the state directly.

```
handleSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.props.setLoading(false);
    if (this._mounted) {
         this.setState({formSubmitted: true, formSuccess: true});
    }
},
handlError(error) {
    console.log("error")

    this.props.setLoading(false);
    if (this._mounted) {
        this.setState({formSubmitted: true, formSuccess: true});
    }
    console.log(error);
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by bind my handle functions @Shubham

Comment: where did I say that, you are using React.createClass you don't need to explicitly bind functions

Comment: is the problem here that I am changing state directly ? @Shubham Khatri

Comment: Apart from this there is nothing in the existing code that may cause this error. Also its not a right method to directly mutate the state